# MongoDB .net driver - Get MongoDB server version

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB .net driver v2.10 and want to know, how I'm able to determine MongoDB version of connected MongoDB Atlas server, for example v4.2.5.

Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB database instance ([IMongoDatabase](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase.htm) interface in .NET) offers [.runCommand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) and you can run [buildInfo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/buildInfo/#dbcmd.buildInfo) to get server veresion:

```
var version = database.RunCommand(
                new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument() {{"buildInfo", 1}}))
                ["version"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help! That was exactly what I searched for!!